# How do I solve Oracle APEX 20.1 sql code editor not Working on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 20.1(Online version) on my chrome browser but I noticed when I click on any code editor window it shows [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capNU.jpg) forever, I can't even close the dialog in this state, instead, I am forced to refresh the whole page. It works on Microsoft Edge browser, on the chrome browser of my laptop, but can't seem to work on this PC only. What can be the issue and how can I solve it?

EDIT:
Fixed the issue by removing some "Dark Theme" extensions from the browser.

Comment: any errors in the google dev console ? Do you have any chrome extensions enabled ? Does it work in an incognito session ?

Comment: Extension was the issue, I had some "Dark Theme" extensions, I removed it and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, but don't was the dart theme.  In my case was a plug-in SMART4Solutions - APEX Plugin , i disabled it and works.